# Logout Problem in Email Application

Tags: jsp

I am developing a small email web application in JSP/Javascript/html. It has a logout link which when clicked redirects to login but the back button still takes the user to his account and therby can access his account again. I am deleting all session variables once the logout is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the cache header you pass to the client browser..

Comment: how can i access cache header?? i am using jsp and javascript